# Haskell: Fix non-exuastive patterns in function

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

I have a program that traverses an AST and returns a map of the functions and variables used and how many times they occurred.  Here it is:

```
import Data.Map
import Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax

increment :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Map a Int
increment a = insertWith (+) a 1

fromName :: Name -> String
fromName (Ident s) = s
fromName (Symbol st) = st

fromQName :: QName -> String
fromQName (Qual _ fn) = fromName fn
fromQName (UnQual n) = fromName n

fromLiteral :: Literal -> String
fromLiteral (Int int) = show int

fromQOp :: QOp -> Map String Int
fromQOp (QVarOp qn) = increment (fromQName qn) empty

fromExp :: Exp -> String 
fromExp (Var qn) = fromQName qn
fromExp (Paren e1) = "()"

vars :: Exp -> Map String Int
vars (Var qn) = increment (fromQName qn) empty
vars (Lit l) = increment (fromLiteral l) empty
vars (Paren e1) = increment "()" (vars e1) 
vars (InfixApp exp1 qop exp2) = increment (fromExp exp1) $ unionWith (+) (fromQOp qop) (vars exp2)

t3 = (InfixApp (Var (UnQual (Ident "x"))) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Paren (InfixApp (Lit (Int 3)) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Lit (Int 2)))))
```

The program runs and even works in most cases, but when I call "vars" on an AST with "Paren" (like t3), I get the following error:

```
fromList *** Exception: parsemap.hs:(22,1)-(23,25): Non-exhaustive patterns in function fromExp
```

I am not sure how to fix this and I could use some help.  By the way, the constructors I am using can be found at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.0.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Exp  in case that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try compiling your programs with `-Wall` to get a warning on non-exhaustive patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, when you look at that [definition of `Exp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.0.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t%3aExp), you can see there's a whole pile of possible constructors. But in your function, you're only checking for two of them.

So what happens if I call `fromExp (Lit l)`? It's undefined, which isn't good. The easiest way to fix this is to add in one more case that covers every other possible constructor:

```
fromExp :: Exp -> String 
fromExp (Var qn)   = fromQName qn
fromExp (Paren e1) = "()"
fromExp _          = "Not defined yet"
```

This way if you call `fromExp` with any other constructor, it will return `"Not defined yet"`.

---

In this specific case, the evaluation is:

```
vars t3
=> vars (InfixApp (Var (UnQual (Ident "x"))) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Paren (InfixApp (Lit (Int 3)) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Lit (Int 2)))))
=> vars (Paren (InfixApp (Lit (Int 3)) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Lit (Int 2)))))
=> vars (InfixApp (Lit (Int 3)) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Lit (Int 2))))
=> fromExp (Lit (Int 3))
```

and there is no `fromExp (Lit l)` definition to evaluate that expression.

Comment: I got it working.  Thank you very much for your help!  I will now start adding definitions for the constructors as you suggested.